# How do you integrate a custom build tool/step for files that works with includes into MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, include

I've been researching how to integrate a Custom Tool into a Visual Studio project (i.e. MSBuild) such that includes will work like they do in C or C++.

In C++, if I have a file, say main.cpp, that includes a header file "foo.h". If that header file changes, and I hit 'Run', an incremental build will be done before launch. Otherwise it just launches without doing anything. This works even if "foo.h" isn't part of the solution, it can be anywhere on my disk. I tried it just now by putting a random file at the root of a drive and adding a relative include path to it to confirm.

I would like to know how I can add the same kind of support to a Custom Tool/Step.

Currently the I have managed to make the build trigger correctly if the file itself changes or if the executable of the Custom Tool changes by adding of those as dependencies of the build in the Properties panel for the Build Step. However, I can't really do the same thing for the includes and I'm hoping I can somehow tap into the same kind of infrastructure that the C++ compiler does to track these.

Comment: The includes are for what type of code? I assume these are not C/C++ include files. The 'infrastructure' that I think you are looking for is part of and specific to the C/C++ compiler. There isn't a generic "recognize an include directive in a source file and find the include file in the include file search paths" feature in MSBuild.

Comment: @JonathanDodds They are not. I'm just wondering what I'm supposed to do on my end because AFAICT my tool/step is not even invoked if MSBuild thinks theres nothing to do. So while the 'infrustructure' might be part of the compiler, it seems to me at least like there is some interaction with MSBuild for it to know to check the included files for modifications.

Comment: Your C++ project file (.vcxproj) will have `Import`s of files specific to C++ projects, e.g. `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`. I don't know the details of how include files are handled but you can use the `/pp` switch to MSBuild to create a file of the project with all imports performed and you can then examine that file to understand what the C++ project support is doing. The C++ project support is **not** part of MSBuild and is available only in C++ project types.